# Reading a hive table in pyspark after altering the schema

Tags: hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I added a column to a hive table:
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMNS (new_col string);

But when I read the table using pyspark (2.1), I see the old schema. How do I download the updated table?

Comment: Did you try using spark.catalog.refreshTable("my_table")